# How do re-render my data when it's changed in next 13?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, prisma, next.js13

How do I go about re-rendering my already fetched data in next-13 when passed as props?
I'm trying to get tasks.data which is fetched in the layout to rerender (useEffect?) inside of my TaskList component when I send a PUT request from another component.

I have tried setting cache: no-store but still have to refresh the page to see changes.

layout:

```
import TaskList from "@/components/tasks/TaskList";
import SetTaskForm from '@/components/tasks/SetTaskForm';
import { getAllTasks } from "@/utils/actions";

export default async function RootLayout({
  children
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  const tasks = await getAllTasks()
  return (
    <html lang='en'>
      <body>
        <main>{children}
          <SetTaskForm />
          <TaskList tasks={tasks} />
        </main>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

TaskList:

```
"use client"
import { TasksProps } from "@/types/taskTypes"
import Task from "./Task"
import { Suspense, useEffect } from "react";

export default function TaskList ({ tasks }: TasksProps) {
  useEffect(() => {

  }, [tasks])
  return (
    <section className="py-9 flex flex-col justify-center">
      <h2 className="text-xl font-semibold mt-6 border-b pb-1 text-center">Tasks</h2>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <ul className="flex flex-col mx-3">
          {tasks?.data?.map((task: TaskProps) => (
            <li key={task.id}>
              <Task 
                key={task._id}    
                title={task.title} 
                body={task.body} 
                bgColor={task.bgColor}
                isCollapsed={task.isCollapsed}
                isCompleted={task.isCompleted}
              />
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </Suspense>
    </section>
  )
}
```

Task:

```
"use client" 

import { deleteTask, toggleCollapseTask, toggleCompletedTask } from "@/utils/actions";
import { TaskProps } from "@/types/taskTypes";
import 'material-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css'
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Task({ id, title, body, isCollapsed, bgColor, isCompleted }: TaskProps) {
  const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(isCollapsed)
  const [completed, setCompleted] = useState(isCompleted)
  const handleCollapse = () => {
    setCollapsed(!collapsed)
    toggleCollapseTask(title, collapsed)
  }
  const handleCompleted = () => {
    setCompleted(!completed)
    toggleCompletedTask(title, completed)
  }
  return (
    <section>
      <div>
        <h1>{title}</h1>
        <span 
          onClick={e => deleteTask(title)}
        >delete</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span onClick={handleCollapse}>expand_more</span>
      {!collapsed && <a>{body}</a>}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

route:

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
import { NextResponse}  from "next/server"

const prisma = new PrismaClient()

export async function GET(request: Request) {
  const data = await prisma.tasks.findMany()
  return NextResponse.json({ data })
}
```

action:

```
"use server";

export async function getAllTasks() {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/getAllTasks"
  );
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
  }
  return res.json();
}
```

Any help or tips on my code greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

From [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#layouts)

> A layout is UI that is shared between multiple pages. On navigation,
> layouts preserve state, remain interactive, and do not re-render.

this is the whole point of the layout. it will prevent unnecessary rerendering of the components. Since layout is not rerendered, you are not fetching the fresh data from the server. You should [revalidate data](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching#static-data-fetching)

```
fetch('https://...', { next: { revalidate: 10 } });
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I tried this setting but unfortunately, I still have to refresh the page after making any changes. Could it have to do with prisma inside the route? edit - it was prisma, I was using a new prismaClient in each route rather than sharing them between routes

Comment: Nevermind, that didn't make it work either, only occasionally refreshing.